# How can I generate HTML reports based on cucumber in Cypress not the JSON reports

Tags: ui-automation, cypress

Implementing the Cucumber usage into the Cypress for Tests but I don't understand how to generate HTML reports for the end test result describing the passed and failed tests as well as scenarios.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there specific code snippet you can post or a detail that describes more 'exactly' what you are executing?

Comment: So , i used feature files to run test cases in cypress. Now ,am able to get Json report generated for feature file about scenario/step passed or failed.Want to generate HTML report from this JSon .

Answer (score 0):

First, you should read this official [cy.docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters.html#Examples) 
and I think you have two options:

- mochawesome.html
- allure2 report more details [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin)

Comment: Mochawesome have already tried and cant be used with cucumber feature files.It works when you run TC using Spec files

Comment: what about allure?